# Quais são as diferenças entre "String" e "str" em Rust?

Tags: string, característica-linguagem, rust

Sei que existem (aparentemente) dois principais tipos de string em Rust:

- `str`, que, até onde sei, é um tipo primitivo;
- `String`, que, até onde eu sei, faz parte da biblioteca padrão `std` da linguagem.

No entanto, fico com algumas perguntas:

1. Quais as diferenças entre eles?
2. Quando usar `str` e quando usar `String`?
3. Por que criar tal distinção?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Quais as diferenças entre eles?

**`str`** é o tipo para guardar textos de uma forma mais bruta. Lembra um pouco o *array* de `char` do C, porque ele é um *array* de bytes (um caractere pode ser formado por mais de 1 byte). Mas é diferente, principalmente porque ele usa um formato de UTF-8 e não ASCII, e claro, ele consegue pegar o tamanho em tempo constante. E também é imutável (em partes).

O tipo permite que mude os elementos existentes, ou seja, os caracteres, mas não pode mudar o tamanho do objeto, esta parte é fixa.

É um tipo por valor, portanto o texto já é o objeto. Geralmente é usada por referência para não ter que copiar de um contexto para outro, e em alguns raros casos acaba sendo alocado no *heap*, e quando precisa disso, tem a solução do `String`.

Um literal de texto é do tipo `&'static str` isso significa que ele será uma referência para o objeto bruto em outro lugar. E esse lugar é a memória estática, mas esse `'static` não indica local, mas sim tempo de vida. É uma forma de dizer que esse objeto durará por todo tem pode vida da aplicação. A grande sacada de Rust é o controle absoluto do tempo de vida sem um coletor de lixo, por isso precisa dizer o tempo de vida em grande parte da situações.

**`String`** é uma *wrapper* para o `str` e é um tipo por referência alocado no *heap*, portanto o tempo de vida tende ser maior e exige um controle menos sofisticado por parte do programador.

Além disso ele é completamente mutável, portanto pode alterar o dado sem ter que copiar para outro objeto, e o gerenciamento de mudanças é todo interno, em vez de ser uma *array* e bytes é uma lista de caracteres (portanto até o tamanho pode mudar).

O tempo de vida dele é ligado à ter referência para ele, então de certa forma podemos dizer que ele é gerenciado por uma forma simplificada de *garbage collector*.

A coleta é feita quando a referência para o objeto deixa de existir. O tipo `String` tem uma referência de propriedade, então há um vínculo direto entre elas.

A classe é bem completinha: [documentação](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html).

```
fn main() {
    let strVar : &'static str = "str";
    let stringVar : String = "String".to_string(); // precisa converter o tipo
    teste(strVar);
    teste(&stringVar);
}

fn teste(texto: &str) {
    println!("Isto é um {}", texto);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WrgWT1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/prfokshb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://repl.it/join/prfokshb-maniero).

> Quando usar str e quando usar String?

A preferência é usar `str` sempre que possível porque imutável, mesmo parcialmente, é melhor, e se você tem controle fácil do tempo de vida encaixa com a filosofia da linguagem de economizar recursos. Se precisa da mutabilidade completa ou deixar o tempo de vida mais livre e controlado pelas circunstâncias, então o `String` é preferível. Ele é menos eficiente no uso geral, mas claro que será mais eficiente que ficar copiando o objeto `str` para lá é para cá por um motivo ou outro.

Não esqueça de estudar [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/index.html).

> Por que criar tal distinção?

Linguagens que buscam eficiência precisam dar a opção mais eficiente e a mais flexível e poderosa. As linguagens de *script* é que optam só pela flexível para ser mais fácil.